# How do I write many parameters to an hdf5 file intelligently?

Tags: c++, c, hdf5

I am trying to use hdf5 to write out the (x,y,z) coordinates that result from Molecular Dynamics simulations. The API is fairly clear on how to do this. My question is about writing the parameters of the simulations. I need to write a very large number of constants, say about 100, to the hdf5 file. I think that this is what attributes are for. Would that be right? My problem is that the attribute API is somewhat cumbersome for this. I'd have to create a very large number of scalar attributes, specify their types, and dimension (which is 1 most of the time), then write them. I'd have to write quite a lot of code. The constants can be `int`, `float`, `unsigned int`, and sometimes some custom types that I have created.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, attributes are the way to go to write this information.

The API can seem rather complex since attributes share most of the semantics as datasets.  You can use any type or shape in an attribute that you can specify with a dataset.  About the only properties attributes don't have are compression and chunking.  (Also attributes can't contain attributes!)

To make the coding less cumbersome you can create a helper function.  If you know (for example) that all your attributes will be 4-byte little-endian scalars, your helper function just needs parent id, name, and value.

Comment: I was worried that would be the case :(. Thanks for you help!